# Case convert in multiples html files

Tags: html, regex, find

I want to find and convert to lower case the content of the firth tag p in multiples html files.
This is possible using regular expressions in sublime text? How can I make it?
thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: is the firth time I do this task, for how i get all p tags in document whit this expression `<p>(?:(?R)|[^<]*+(?:(?!</?p\b)<[^<]*+)*+)*+</p>`

Comment: I get the same result with `<p.*?>(.|\n)*?</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `\L` in sublime text to convert letters to lower cases:

Find What: `(<p.*?>)((.|\n)*?)(</p>)`
Replace With: `\1\L\2\4`